# Can an instance template contain multiple docker images?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a instance template, but I need to have 2 docker images for this template.

One will be a NGINX image and the other will be my application code (web service).

Is it possible to have multiple images in a instance template?

I want to use this instance template for a managed instance group.

Comment: Is your goal to run one instance with two Docker containers, or different instances with different Docker containers.

Comment: the goal is to have identical instances (hence the template), but I need to run NGINX and my custom web app - so 2 docker images.  In DEV I would use docker-compose to run this, but I want to bundle this into a single instance template and then use managed instance groups to manage a cluster of them.

Comment: Container OS or standard Compute Engine?

Comment: @JohnHanley haven't looked into container OS so not sure at this time.

Comment: I would use Container OS and Docker Compose. This article will walk you. Please post an answer once you set this up. https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os

Comment: @JohnHanley When creating an instance template, you can create one using a a docker image in googles registry.  But if I have multiple instances for my template, what options do I have to creating the template?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley after setting up container os and docker compose, how do I create the template?  What options do I have?  Is it basically creating a VM instance and then a template based on that instance?

Comment: Did you read the article that I sent you? If, yes create a new question with the problems that you are having in detail with error messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

#### Each VM runs 2 container images (your case)

If each VM runs 2 container images (a NGINX + a custom web service), then I see no problem to create an *instance template* running these two containers, and use this *instance template* in your *Managed Instance Group*. Each VM will have the same application running on it, but here, under the hood, your application is just composed of two containers (you can even group these containers with `docker-compose`).

#### Each VM runs with a different container image

*Managed [instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/)* are groups of multiple **identical** VMs (same instance template). It should be identical VMs because, for example, managed instance groups offers load-balancing and autoscaling, and it would make no sense to load-balance traffic amongst different VMs with different applications.

If you want to have an instance group with **heterogeneous** VMs (different instance templates, each one running a different container), then you can take a look at [Unmanaged instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances) :

> Unmanaged instance groups are collections of instances that are not necessarily identical and do not share a common instance template. [...]. However, you should always use managed instance groups unless your applications require you to group instances together that are not identical.

Comment: the VM's are identical, but they each will have multiple docker images running.  Does that make sense?  2 identical docker images for a template, is that possible?

Comment: Oh I see, I've quite misunderstood the question. Then if 2 containers are running on each VM, yes you can go for a managed instance group, with an instance template containing 2 containers. I'll update the answer.